# WP-CLI Toggle WP_DEBUG

Tags: wordpress, command-line-interface, wp-cli

I'm looking to toggle the WP_DEBUG value within a WP-CLI script.
Is there any option doing so AFTER the wp-config.php file was created?

(I know we can add extra PHP when creating the wp-config.php file, but once that's done, is there a way to turn off the WP_DEBUG state during the script?)

Thanks.

Comment: Good question, I just keep it set to true, and comment / un-comment when needed - not a huge deal if you're quick with `vi` but still not a great solution. hoping someone has the real answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Woohoo! Native support added since WP-CLI version 1.5 -

https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/config/set/

**Example:**

```
# Set the WP_DEBUG constant to true.
$ wp config set WP_DEBUG true --raw
```

Comment: Note, this only works if you already have the WP_DEBUG variable in your config file. By default a WP CLI `wp config create` setup doesn't include this var so unfortunately you'd have to add `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` to the file before you can then use this command. Which kind of defeats the purpose. Bummer!

Answer (score 10):

To extend on @tlt2w answer posted [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49105953/586898), I'm using this combo:

```
wp config set --raw WP_DEBUG true
wp config set --raw WP_DEBUG_LOG true
wp config set --raw WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY false

# show logs:
# clear; tail -f wp-content/debug.log -n0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `wp config get` to determine if debug is enabled or not, however today there is no way to set that value via WP-CLI.

That said, just wrote a bash command that can toggle the value for you.

You can run it in the same directory you have your `wp-config.php`:

```
data=`egrep "'WP_DEBUG'" wp-config.php | egrep -o "(true|false)"`; [[ $data == true ]] && newdata=false || newdata=true; sed -i "s/'WP_DEBUG'.*/'WP_DEBUG', $newdata\)\;/g" wp-config.php
```

Every time you run it, the `WP_DEBUG` constant value will switch from `true` to `false` or vice-versa.

Unfortunately there is no way to toggle the `WP_DEBUG` value during the script execution, since the value was already defined in `wp-config.php` file.